# Scala Parallelism

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, parallel-processing

I am trying to call .par on a Scala vector version 2.13.2 but get the error

```
Error:(1, 25) object parallel is not a member of package collection
import scala.collection.parallel.CollectionConverters._
```

I have imported

```
import scala.collection.parallel.CollectionConverters._
```

and have also added the dependency

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parallel-collections" % "0.2.0"
```

What's wrong?

Comment: That should work. Did you reload sbt project after adding dependency?

Comment: yes I rebuilt the sbt project. I am writing the .par and imports in a scala scratch file but still get the error

Comment: I am unable to replicate issue with latest IntelliJ + Scala Plugin.

Comment: tried it within a package in src/main/scala files and it worked. Any idea why it is not working in scala.scratch files?

Comment: Does it work in Scala Worksheet?

Comment: yes, but not in a scratch file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214699/discussion-between-seller-central-and-mario-galic).